# JQuery: Select html of an element, inclusive?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

What's the best way to select the html of an element, inclusive?  For example:

```
<div id="testDiv" class="testClass">
  This is just a test.
</div>
```

Whereas `$('#testDiv').html()` returns `"This is just a test."`, I would a selector that returns:

`<div id="testDiv" class="testClass">This is just a test.</div>`.

Thank you for your replies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [this `jQuery.outerHTML()` implementation](http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2007/06/17/jquery-snippets-outerhtml).

```
jQuery.fn.outerHTML = function() {
    return $('<div>').append( this.eq(0).clone() ).html();
};
```

Comment: @Esteban You can add `return this;` so that it is chainable.

Answer (score 0):

> This is similar to the accepted answer, **adding 2 improvements**:

1. A return line so that this is chainable. Example: $(select).outerHTML().css(x);
2. Declared in such a way as to not interfere with other code. See https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

> **Here is the code:**

```
// add outer html selector
(function ($) {
    $.fn.outerHTML = function() {
        return $('<div>').append( this.eq(0).clone() ).html();
        return this;
    };
}(jQuery));
```