# How do I get HTML corresponding to current DOM tree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

jQuery("html").html() seems to retrieves most of it, except for the wrapping  tag.

DOM is heavily modified, so original source is of not that much use.

- Is it reliable?
- Is it a good idea to just take jQuery's output and wrap ... around it? I can see at least some doctype problems here, and inclusion of scripts which shouldn't be rerun.
- Any better way?

EDIT: jQuery("").append(jQuery("html").clone()).html() almost works, except for doctype. Is there an easy way to get it?

EDIT 2: I need the doctype mostly to get proper quirk/almoststandards/standards mode. document.compatMode has half of it, is it enough?

Comment: It might help if we knew what you were attempting to do with the HTML.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526407/jquery-select-html-of-an-element-inclusive or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917020/how-to-get-html-string-of-a-child-tag-and-parent-tag-using-jquery or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917040/can-i-get-the-full-html-represenation-of-an-htmlelment-dom-object or (less jquery-specific) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763479/how-to-get-the-html-for-a-dom-element-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

jQuery uses `innerHTML` to get the HTML. You're not going to get the exact DOM state using this attribute. For example the content of `input` values or the state of a `select` box will not stay the same unless you properly modify it before calling `innerHTML`.

What is this `wrapping` tag you're talking about? For most of it, innerHTML should work fine.

For example, I use this code for the state of `select` and `input` boxes.

```
// it's defaultValue so we can use innerHTML
$("#divContentInside input").each(function () {
    this.defaultValue = this.value;
});
// go through each select and replace
// it's selection so we can use innerHTML
$("#divContentInside select > option").each(function () {
    if (this.selected) {
        this.setAttribute("selected", true);
    } else {
        this.removeAttribute("selected");
    }
});
```

I haven't found issues with state consistency of other elements, but there probably is.

Answer (score 2):

You can use standard DOM commands:

To get the innerHTML of the HTML tag

```
document.body.parentNode.innerHTML
```

To get the Doctype information

```
document.body.parentNode.previousSibling;
```

Comment: Thanks, naive $('<div />').append($(document.body.parentNode.previousSibling) ).html() raises "Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy" exception, but I should be able to figure out the doctype from the node.

Comment: You can read the properties of the object returned by document.body.parentNode.previousSibling, it doesn't have html

Answer (score 0):

http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2007/06/17/jquery-snippets-outerhtml/
outerHTML implementation for jquery.

**Edit**

Doing a quick search came in the document.doctype option, [here is a full reference](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/DocumentType) to it. Removed the old and now unnecessary text/code.

Comment: Requesting the source won't do much good, as DOM gets modified and it's the modified state I'm interested in.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried `$(document).html()`