# How do I manipulate data on a webpage from node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I'm kind of new to node.js and Javascript so forgive me if the question is poorly worded.

I'm using cheeriojs to scrape data from a site. I'm running the js file that scrapes the data in the command line and it outputs the data I want, but I want to be able to have access to this data on a webpage, where I can put it into a table. (or anything else I want for that matter). How exactly do I do this?

Thank you

Comment: Can you add some examples of what you mean? Like a simple use case. From what I can understand, you have scraped a page using cheeriojs using nodejs, however you want to serve a webpage to a browser using nodejs, edit the webpage that is served to the browser, send it back to nodejs, and save it?

Comment: Yes, that sounds like what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn how to use `express`.

Serve the page to a browser, by reading the file and serving it with an `express` endpoint, or to `curl` or something. ie `curl localhost:8080/your-endpoint`

Using the browser manipulate the page inside of the browsers dev tools.

Figure out how to get the current DOM as an html string.

Figure out how to use the `fetch` API inside of a browser such as `fetch(url, {method: 'POST'}).then(...)`

After manipulating the DOM with the browsers dev tools.

`POST` the results back to `express` on the nodejs server.

Save the `req.body` or `req.data` or `req.params` to a file.

Side notes: 
 - figure out what a callback is, figure out how promises work
 - do some research on express middleware
 - look into setInterval, setTimeout

Related:

- [Node.js quick file server (static files over HTTP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333790/node-js-quick-file-server-static-files-over-http)
- [How do I get HTML corresponding to current DOM tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120060/how-do-i-get-html-corresponding-to-current-dom-tree)
- [fetch(), how do you make a non-cached request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29246444/fetch-how-do-you-make-a-non-cached-request)
- [What is Express.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12616153/what-is-express-js)
- https://github.com/Concatapult/node-catapult/blob/master/server/index.js
- [Writing files in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496710/writing-files-in-node-js)

Other options, use a text editor, use `sed`, `grep`, `awk`, `bash`, or something else that doesn't require serving files to a browser?